# SecurityException: not allowed to perform OP_READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, security, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

User is reporting my app crashes with this error trace

```
java.lang.SecurityException: com.android.phone from uid 10134 not allowed to perform OP_READ_PHONE_STATE
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
at com.android.internal.telephony.IPhoneSubInfo$Stub$Proxy.getVoiceMailNumberForSubscriber(IPhoneSubInfo.java:858)
at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getVoiceMailNumber(TelephonyManager.java:2383)
at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getVoiceMailNumber(TelephonyManager.java:2366)
```

So far only one user has reported this problem.  Several thousand other users are running this version of the app with no apparent problems.

The exception is thrown when we call  `TelephonyManager.getVoiceMailNumber()`.  This operation is documented as required the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission, which has absolutely, positively been granted.

I tracked down the `OP_READ_PHONE_STATE` permission to the `android.apps.AppOpsManager` class but can not figure out exactly what it is unhappy about.

Can anyone explain just what is happening and what needs to be done to fix things.

Thanks,
-Ken

Comment: Did you check for runtime permissions for read_phone_state?  Could they manually have removed your permissions, either from app settings or via cyanogenmod (or similar tools)?

Comment: The code checks for the standard READ_PHONE_STATE permission   before executing the getVoiceMailNumber() call.  And the app generated support email lists all of the requested permissions that have not been granted.  READ_PHONE_STATE was not reported in that list.  I am about as certain as I can be that the READ_PHONE_STATE permission has been granteddd.

Comment: Crazy this was seen so long ago.  We're seeing tons of these now, only from Samsungs, and only from those running nougat.

Comment: I'm seeing this on Samsung S8/S8+ with Android 7 too. Do you know if this is mostly one carrier over another?

Comment: is it still happening? can anybody confirm? Samsung sucks!

Comment: Any updated with this problem? I have the same problem but in others devices. Always in nougat, not in Oreo or Mashmallow.

Comment: @kencorbin, how did you solve this issue? It happens to me as well.

Comment: @VíctorSantoja, did you solve this?

Comment: @pforhan, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes. this problem still exists. Even having runtime permissions doesn't solve it. Device is Asus.

Comment: My guess for what happens here: The mobile apparently has a modified version of `com.android.phone` app. When you call the method you request that information from the phone app. The app disregards the fact that docs say it should grant the requests for apps that have the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. As a result, a `SecurityException` is raised.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for that method in AOSP eventually leads to the [cheakReadPhoneState() method](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/telephony/common/com/android/internal/telephony/TelephonyPermissions.java;l=132;drc=master;bpv=0;bpt=1).

In Android 6, that method was [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-6.0.1_r80:frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/PhoneSubInfo.java;l=368;bpv=0;bpt=0).

In both cases, it looks pretty similar. Here's the Android 6 code:

```
private boolean checkReadPhoneState(String callingPackage, String message) {
    try {
        mContext.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE, message);

        // SKIP checking run-time OP_READ_PHONE_STATE since self or using PRIVILEGED
        return true;
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        mContext.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                message);
    }

    return mAppOps.noteOp(AppOpsManager.OP_READ_PHONE_STATE, Binder.getCallingUid(),
        callingPackage) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;
}
```

First it checks to see if `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` is granted. If it is, then the rest of the code is short-circuited and it returns true. Otherwise, it makes sure that `READ_PHONE_STATE` is granted, throwing a SecurityException otherwise.

Finally, if `READ_PHONE_STATE` is granted, it makes sure that `OP_READ_PHONE_STATE` is *also* granted. I'm not entirely sure why it's doing that, but that's where the problem is coming from. Whichever devices this error is occurring on have changed something with the way runtime permissions work. When the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission is granted, the `OP_READ_PHONE_STATE` op should also be granted, but the system is revoking that op for whatever reason.

(It's also possible that the user is using an app to manage app-ops and has revoked it manually.)

For fixing it, I don't really think you can. The best you can do is catch the error and ask that users run an ADB command to manually grant the op:

`adb shell appops set com.your.packagename READ_PHONE_STATE allow`.

Comment: The app op string is different: `adb shell appops set com.your.packagename android:read_phone_state allow` See [source](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/oreo-cts-release:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/AppOpsManager.java;l=319).

Comment: @EugenPechanec you can use the op constant name without the `OP_` prefix as well as the proper String value. Check out [the last branch of the strOpToOp() method](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/appop/AppOpsService.java;l=4558;bpv=0;bpt=0) and [the sOpNames array](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/AppOpsManager.java;l=1817).

Comment: You're right, this is just what I needed, thanks! Works on [Lollipop](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/lollipop-mr1-cts-release:frameworks/base/cmds/appops/src/com/android/commands/appops/AppOpsCommand.java;l=89), too, actually even better because many app op names were missing until Pie.