# com.android.phone from uid 10400 not allowed to perform OP_READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, android-permissions

The line:

```
final TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
```

is throwing this error only on the Samsung Galaxy note 5 running android 7.0. And this only happened after I upgraded Google-Services to 3.1.0. I have the line
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`
In my manifest file and

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

is returning true. Is this a bug with 7.0 on the Note 5 or am I getting the permissions wrong somehow?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694220/securityexception-not-allowed-to-perform-op-read-phone-state

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The first time the app is installed, you must enable *Phone* permission under *Settings->Apps->App Name->Permissions*.

For Android 6.0 and up, this is true for the following permissions ([ref](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6270602)):

- Body Sensors
- Calendar
- Camera
- Contacts
- Location
- Microphone
- Phone
- SMS
- Storage

Comment: For all apps (yours, Phone, and Play Services)?

Comment: yes. I went through and made sure. I find it most odd it seems to be only happening on the one test device though even when I uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Hm. Sorry, I was hoping I might be able to help even though I don't have that configuration at my disposal. Looks like you are doing everything correctly and it may be a device-specific issue. Your code as shown above works on my 7.x devices. If I can track down a 5 around here, I will try it.